# How to check objects is in Other document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two documents and i want to show isfav is in Product List when the user logged in

First Product

```
{
  _id: 1231,
  name: 'Product 1'  
}
{
  _id: 1232,
  name: 'Product 2'  
}
{
  _id: 1233,
  name: 'Product 3'  
}
```

Now I want to do a $lookup in user document where my favorite products are save in objects

Second Document User

```
{
  _id: 123abcd,
  name: 'ABCD' ,
  favProducts :[1211,1232] 
}
```

I want result Like

```
{
  _id: 1231,
  name: 'Product 1' ,
  isFav: true 
}
{
  _id: 1232,
  name: 'Product 2'  ,
  isFav: true 
}
{
  _id: 1233,
  name: 'Product 3'  ,
  isFav: false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an aggregation pipeline that retrieves a full product list that indicates if a given user has favorited the product or not.

```
[
    {$lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'favProducts',
      as: 'users'
    }}, 
    {$unwind: {
      path: "$users",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }}, 
    {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      isFav : { $max : 
      { $eq : [ "$users._id", "user2" ] } }
    }}
]
```

`$lookup` pulls information from the `users` collection into the `products` collection and puts it into an array named `users`.

`$unwind` unwinds the `users` array and creates an object for each product/user combination.

`$group` puts the documents back together by `_id`.  It uses `$max` to check if any of the user _id's match the id of the user who is logged in.